# Движение всех UI элементов при появлении нового

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь написать скрипт для UI элементов. Смысл в том, что при нажатии на кнопку создается скриншот некой игровой области, я хочу что бы все предыдущие скриншоты сдвигались при появлении нового. Не совсем понимаю как это сделать, создал List в который добавляются все скриншоты, но если их пытаться двигать через foreach то двигаются они не правильно, с каждым разом все больше.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Желательно скрин логики твоего передвижения